# Error when adding a new column to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to modify .csv files in a folder. The files contain flight information from years 2011-2016.

However, year information cannot be found in the values.

I would like to solve this by using the filename of the .csv file which contains the year. I am adding a new 'year' column after reading it into a pandas dataframe. I will then export the modified file to a new .csv with only the year as its filename.

However, I am encountering this error:

*ValueError:Length of values does not match length of index*

Code below for your reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import re
import os

path = r'data_caap/'                   
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))


for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    year= re.findall(r'\d{4}', f)

    #Error here
    df['year']=year
    #Error here

    df.to_csv(year)
```

Comment: can you try `print(re.findall(r'\d{4}', f))`?

Comment: ['2001']
['2002']
['2003']
['2004']
['2005']
['2006']
['2007']
['2008']
['2009']
['2010']
['2011']
['2012']
['2013']
['2014']
['2015']
['2016']

Comment: Must be `df['year']=year[0]`. `findall` returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

Found the cause of the error.

> Must be df['year']=year[0]. findall returns a list. – DyZ

Thanks a lot @Dyz